# IIS rewrite configuration duplicates the path in address bar

Tags: angular, iis

I have an Angular website hosted in IIS. Initially the refresh wasn't working and was displaying a `404 error`. Going through some of the solutions provided on this site, I installed the rewrite module of IIS and configured my `web.config` file as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The refresh is working now and I get redirected to the same page, however the path string gets duplicated. e.g. if the original path was `http://localhost/login` , then on refresh it becomes : `http://localhost/login/login`

A second refresh leads me to a blank page.

Is there anything wrong with the `web.config` file or are there any additional changes needed for the desired behavior?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by rewrite rule? Do you want to redirect the URL to the default page index.html?

Comment: just the usual behavior, when I refresh this link ```http://localhost/login``` it should stay at the same link

Comment: Please try to use FRT to trace rewrite rules,  you can see how the rules are used internally https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules